# How can I asynchronously stream loaded objects from a list of futures in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, stream, future

I have a list of objects that can be loaded by calling the function object.load().
This function returns a loaded version of the same object asynchronously.
I want call the load() funcion of all objects in a list at the same time and stream the loaded versions as soon as they finish loading.
The code below works but the program is loading one object at a time.

Sender:

```
Stream<ImageIconModel> streamLoadedIcons() async* {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageIconModels.length; i++) {
      yield await imageIconModels[i].load().then((loadedIconModel) {
        return loadedIconModel;
      });
    }
  }
```

Receiver:

```
    await for (var loadedIcon in streamLoadedIcons()) {
     final var result = doSomething(loadedIcon);
     yield result;
    }
```

The main problem is:
In the sender, if I await each load() call, it will do every step in the loop awaiting the load() to finish.
But if I remove the "await", I would be returning a future, not the loaded icon.

Comment: something like this? `ctrl = StreamController(); imageIconModels.forEach((i) => i.load().then(ctrl.add)); return ctrl.stream;`

Comment: Thanks for your help @pskink!
But `ctrl.stream` returns a `_ControllerStream<dynamic>` instead of a `Stream<ImageIconModel>`.
I will research more about similar methods to see if I can make it work or convert it to the proper type.

Comment: `ctrl = StreamController<ImageIconModel>();`

Answer (score 1):

You need [`Stream.fromFutures`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-async/Stream/Stream.fromFutures.html).

```dart
final loadedIconModelStream = Stream.fromFutures([
  for (final iconModel in imageIconModels) iconModel.load(),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both @hacker1024 an @pskink answers successfully answered my question!
But neither one worked as it supposed to and I think I discovered why.

I substituted the load() method for a Future.delayed(duration: random), and then the program worked as it intended to.

So what I think happened is that probably the lib I'm using to load the images (multi_image_picker: ^4.7.14) is accessing the phone files synchronously.
So even if I try to load every image at same time, it will do the task synchronously and return every image at the order I called them to load.

Thank you both for the answer!